# Numeros float, que siempre tienen la separación

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, base-de-datos

Tengo una duda realmente sencilla de resolver, supongo.

La cosa es que tengo un campo en mi bbdd que se llama "precio", en ese campo van a entrar valores desde 200€ hasta 200.000€, la cosa es que yo en ese campo le he puesto un **type float(9,3)**.

*En números grandes genial, ya que me muestra 56.000€, pero en los pequeños , por ejemplo en un precio de 500€ real, me muestra 500.000€ , como que le mete obligatoriamente ese punto detras, seguido de esos 3 zeros, supongo que algo deberé estar haciendo mal.

Gracias!

Comment: no. el punto es el separador decimal... no es que en numeros grandes anda bien.. lo que pasa, es que estas mirando otra cosa distinta a lo que vos pensas...

Comment: No uses float o double para importes, tienen errores de redondeo. Usa un tipo con un número fijo de decimales o mejor aún, si existe, un tipo específico para moneda

Comment: Entonces que "datatype" recomiendan? INT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los tipos de datos Float y Double (tipos de datos de punto flotante) en MySql (y otros DBMS) son aproximados, no deberías usarlos para almacenar datos que requieren precisión y exactitud, en su lugar deberías usar DECIMAL(TotalDigitosEntero, DigistosDespuesSeparadorDecimalEntero) o NUMERIC(TotalDigitosEntero, DigistosDespuesSeparadorDecimalEntero) (tipos de datos de punto fijo) ya que guardan los valores exactos.

Ej: DECIMAL(5,2) permite guardar cualquier valor con 5 dígitos (en total) y dos decimales, en este caso los valores comprendidos entre -999.99 y 999.99.

El tipo de datos INT (sinónimo de INTEGER) se utiliza para almacenar enteros.

[Documentación tipos de datos numéricos MySql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-types.html)